# Dynamic height and width of texView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am beginner of iPhone developer. I want to give dynamic width and height on textView I have used below code and when I write in textview at that time it will go up side on view not write actual size of frame.

I have used

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    writTxtView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,90,50,40)];
    [writTxtView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:writTxtView];

    writeTxt = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,40)];
    [writeTxt setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [writeTxt setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
    [writeTxt setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [writeTxt setDelegate:self];
    [writeTxt setHidden:YES];
    [writTxtView addSubview:writeTxt];

}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    tooDoneBar.hidden = NO;

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        //[textView resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }

    textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    CGFloat maxHeight = 312.0f;
    NSLog(@"MytextViewframe :%@",NSStringFromCGRect(textView.frame));
    CGFloat fixedWidth = writTxtView.frame.origin.x;
    NSLog(@"FixedWidth :%f",fixedWidth);
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    NSLog(@"newFrame :%@",NSStringFromCGRect(textView.frame));
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), fminf(newSize.height, maxHeight));
    textView.frame = newFrame;
    NSLog(@"OthernewFrame :%@",NSStringFromCGRect(textView.frame));
    writTxtView.frame = newFrame;
    return YES;
}
```

so, give any suggestion and source code which apply in my code

Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

Use the textView Delegates and use it

```
 [textView sizeToFit];
 [textView layoutIfNeeded];
```

For Ex :

```
 -(BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{

       // NSLog(@"%d", textView.tag);
        frame = textView.frame;
        frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
        frame.size.width = 730;

        if (frame.size.height == textView.frame.size.height) {
             NSLog(@"NO needs to Change");
        } else {
            textView.frame = frame;
            NSLog(@"NEeds to Change");
        }
        [textView sizeToFit];
        [textView layoutIfNeeded];
        return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    -(CGSize)GetHeightDyanamic:(UITextView*)textview
     {
       NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [textview.text length]);
       CGSize constraint;
      if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
      constraint= CGSizeMake(722 ,MAXFLOAT);
     }
    else
      constraint= CGSizeMake(287 ,MAXFLOAT);
      CGSize size;
      NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
     float ver_float = [ver floatValue];
     if (ver_float>6.0) {
        NSDictionary *attributes = [textview.attributedText attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:&range];
       CGSize boundingBox = [textview.text boundingRectWithSize:constraint options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:nil].size;

      size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width), ceil(boundingBox.height));
    }
  else{


      size = [textview.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    }
   return size;
}
```

i hope its useful
  its working for UIlabel...so..try  it